# How do I get the max memory usage of my program in OSX

Tags: c++, macos, profiling

I've writen a program in c++, compiled it with Intels C++ compiler and is running it under Mac OSX.

I would like to profile the maximum memory usage of the program, what tool would I use for this?

I would prefer a commandline tool, for scripting purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I have not tried this, [Valgrind Massif profiling tool](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) should help to do this. From 
[Massif manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html#ms-manual.not-measured):

> By default Massif measures only heap memory, i.e. memory allocated
>   with malloc, calloc, realloc, memalign, new, new[], and a
>   few other. Therefore, the numbers reported by Massif may be
>   significantly smaller than those reported by tools such as top that
>   measure a program's total size in memory. However, if you wish to
>   measure all the memory used by your program, you can use the
>   --pages-as-heap=yes.

Comment: Yes it does. add [valgrind doc link](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html#ms-manual.not-measured) to your answer.

Comment: Is there a way to make the massif tool return the maximum combined allocation size of an execution? Getting large stack-traces and sample data in a seperate file seems overkill.

Comment: No, it looks like you have to collect profiling data in any case and then parse it by `ms_print` to get maximum allocation size.